# Is there a quicker way to go from the cmd window to normal mode?

Tags: vim-windows

Is it possible to map `<esc>` to close the cmd window and go to normal mode? Currently pressing
`<C-c>` closes the cmd window but takes you into Cmdline mode. So you have
to press either `<C-c>` again or `<esc>` to go to normal mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it possible to map `<esc>`

Remapping <kbd>Esc</kbd> is strongly discouraged, as it may interfere with normal keycode processing in terminal version of Vim (see, for example, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940801/mapping-esc-in-vimrc-causes-bizarre-arrow-behaviour)).

But, of course, you can remap something else **for that particular `<buffer>` only**, so your mapping can't do bad things to other windows (BTW. this technique is also suggested under `:h cmdwin`):

```
autocmd CmdwinEnter * nnoremap <silent><buffer>ZQ <C-C><Esc>
```

In fact, this is a very common pattern in Vim to fine-tune mappings for specific windows, and as such it's useful to add it to your toolbox. A pair of examples taken from my vimrc to illustrate this capability:

```
augroup vimrc | au!
    ...
    " 'q' to close a non-modifiable window/buffer (e.g. 'help')
    autocmd BufWinEnter * if !&modifiable | nnoremap <buffer>q ZQ | endif
    " <F5> to execute script
    autocmd FileType vim nnoremap <buffer><silent><F5> :update \| source %<CR>
    autocmd FileType sh nnoremap <buffer><silent><F5> :update \|
        \ execute 'terminal' &shell expand('%:S')<CR>
    ...
augroup end
```

Comment: Great inspiration in that snippet. If found that mapping to `<C-c><C-c>` worked
better as `<C-c><esc>` was execting the command. Also mapping <esc> in this
situation worked like a charm.


noremap : q:i
             autocmd CmdwinEnter * nnoremap <buffer><esc> <C-c><C-c>

Comment: Some of your filetype commands may be better off in .vim/after/ftplugin (leveraging existing machinery, as it were)

Comment: *"You should never map Esc."* Why not? Do you have a citation for that? Looks like the OP was pretty happy with a solution remapping Esc from there, and I don't really see any problems with it... I also fail to see how the last part on mapping "q" and F5 is in any way relevant to the question. So while your answer *does* somewhat answer the question, it could be improved by making it shorter and actually using the suggested/requested keybinding...

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Well, I really don't see what is the benefit of `after/ftplugin` here. Care to give an example?

Comment: @filbranden I added a pair of mappings, because I thought it could be useful for OP. You may have a different opinion, of course.

Comment: @filbranden mapping esc tends to... break things. Arrow keys and other special key sequences that are actually escape followed by codes.

Comment: `Looks like the OP was pretty happy with a solution remapping Esc from there` He might be using gvim which seems not to suffer from this issue. However, remapping 'esc' still should be considered as a bad idea in general.

Comment: Saying "mapping ESC is not advisable in many cases, it can be problematic because arrow keys and other special key sequences start with ESC and can break in some cases" is probably fine. Saying "never do it" is probably too much. Also, I'm not questioning the usefulness of the other mappings, I do agree they're useful, I just really fail to see the connection with the command window and the question on how to close it... Perhaps there's a connection, if so, would you expand the answer to explain it?

Comment: I can confirm the arrow keys are broken for normal mode in this buffer. Is there a list of the other special key sequences somewhere?

Comment: @SwissFrank Use `:set termcap`. `esc` is rendered as `^[`.